# which order is better when defining the local var?

Tags: java

```java
PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
Map<String, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    for (int i = 0; i < propertyDescriptors.length; i++) {
             ......
            returnMap.put(propertyName, result);

            }
```

```java
Map<String, Object> returnMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
PropertyDescriptor[] propertyDescriptors = beanInfo.getPropertyDescriptors();
    for (int i = 0; i < propertyDescriptors.length; i++) {
             ......
            returnMap.put(propertyName, result);

            }
```

which order is better when defining the local var? if define it as the first code, it will make too long distance between propertyDescriptors  defined and their use, but defined it as the second code, it will long distance between map defined or map use.

So which is rule to order them ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not different. If having to choose one, i will choose the second. Because i think that you care about the Map more than the PropertyDescriptor and the PropertyDescripor is only used to generate the Map values. So it is a intermediate variable relative to the Map and should be defined where it is used.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I tend to make my more important objects higher up in my code. It doesn't make a difference functionally, but I like to keep it all organized that way, and I typically comment on each of them so if someone is reading it they can decipher it a little quicker. So, personally I would go with the second, but I would probably make the Map at the top of the area it is used in, especially if its also used in other places.

Answer (score 0):

No difference. Just use whichever one you think looks better!

Comment: So I can't make a decide. Though it is not am import issue. but it is interest one for me